# How to prevent tabulated outputs of functons being messed up when using 'watch' over ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, watch, tabulation

While ssh-ing into my server I want to be able to monitor for activity over certain port using `netstat`. Instead of running it manually I want to automate it with `watch`. While the command (`sudo netstat -apon | grep 44002`) running by itself gives the right output

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44002         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1750/sshd: mainuser  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:44002               :::*                    LISTEN      1750/sshd: mainuser  off (0.00/0/0)
```

when combined with `watch` the output gets garbled looking roughly like:

```
tcp        0                                0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                 1
c2-user  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6
c2-user  off (0.00/0/0)
 0 ::1:44002
```

I suspect this has something to do with the witdh of the terminal not being handled properly. How can I fix this?

Comment: When it's "combined with watch", what is the actual command that you're running?

Comment: @Kenster I run `watch sh -c 'sudo netstat -apon | grep 44002'`.